# .NET Graphics.FillEllipse()

Tags: c#, .net, graphics, drawing, drawellipse

So the .NET documentation says that this creates a filled ellipse with the UPPER LEFT CORNER at the X,Y coordinate specified.

But I need the ellipse to be CENTERED on the X,Y coordinate I supplied.

How do I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure if there is a way to change its centering but you could always go: x += width/2; and y += height/2;

Comment: @Rhexis: you're correct except it should be `-=`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the desired center point, decrease X by half of the width and decrease Y by half of the height.

Comment: @user1653653: no problem; we've all been there. Glad to help.